# Error: Conflict: Constraint fourseven:scss@3.4.1 is not satisfied by fourseven:scss 3.2.0

Tags: meteor, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to add [scss](https://atmospherejs.com/fourseven/scss) and [foundation](https://atmospherejs.com/zurb/foundation-sites) to a meteor project. I'm getting the following error:

```
error: Conflict: Constraint fourseven:scss@3.4.1 is not satisfied by
fourseven:scss 3.2.0.
Constraints on package "fourseven:scss":
* fourseven:scss@3.4.1 <- zurb:foundation-sites 6.2.1_2

Conflict: Constraint ecmascript@0.1.6 is not satisfied by ecmascript 0.1.4.
Constraints on package "ecmascript":
* ecmascript@=0.1.4 <- top level
* ecmascript@0.1.4 <- coffeescript 1.0.9 <- cosmos:browserify 0.7.0
* ecmascript@0.1.3 <- caching-compiler 1.0.0 <- caching-html-compiler 1.0.1 <-
templating 1.1.3 <- accounts-ui-unstyled 1.1.8
* ecmascript@0.1.3 <- caching-compiler 1.0.0 <- coffeescript 1.0.9 <-
cosmos:browserify 0.7.0
* ecmascript@0.1.3 <- caching-compiler 1.0.0 <- cosmos:browserify 0.7.0
* ecmascript@0.1.3 <- accounts-base 1.2.1 <- accounts-password 1.1.3
* ecmascript@0.1.3 <- ddp-server 1.2.1 <- ddp 1.2.2 <- accounts-base 1.2.1 <-
accounts-password 1.1.3
* ecmascript@0.1.3 <- ddp-server 1.2.1 <- ddp 1.2.2 <- accounts-password 1.1.3
* ecmascript@0.1.4 <- templating 1.1.3 <- accounts-ui-unstyled 1.1.8
* ecmascript@0.1.3 <- caching-html-compiler 1.0.1 <- templating 1.1.3 <-
accounts-ui-unstyled 1.1.8
* ecmascript@0.1.3 <- templating-tools 1.0.0 <- caching-html-compiler 1.0.1 <-
templating 1.1.3 <- accounts-ui-unstyled 1.1.8
* ecmascript@0.1.3 <- templating-tools 1.0.0 <- templating 1.1.3 <-
accounts-ui-unstyled 1.1.8
* ecmascript@0.1.4 <- less 2.5.0_2 <- accounts-ui-unstyled 1.1.8
* ecmascript@0.1.6 <- zurb:foundation-sites 6.2.1_2
```

I found someone who is [having a similar problem](https://github.com/rikonor/meteor-autoform-image-gallery/issues/1), but I haven't specified a version for either package.

Comment: How did you solve the conflict?